# matcheckbox selecting outside the checkbox how can we stop the event triggering outside the checkbox

Tags: angular

iam using the matcheckbox in the application table , where it is checking outside the checkbox also.can anyone give a solution for that how can we fix that issue , and also why it is selecting even if we click outside the checkbox.Thanks in advance
html

````
  <ng-container matColumnDef="select">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
            <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null"
                          [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
                          [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()"
                          [aria-label]="checkboxLabel()">
            </mat-checkbox>
         </mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
            <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                          (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"
                          [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)"
                          [aria-label]="checkboxLabel(row)">
            </mat-checkbox>
          </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
```
ts
```
 /** Whether the number of selected elements matches the total number of rows. */
  isAllSelected() {
    const numSelected = this.selection.selected.length;
    const numRows = this.dataSource.data.length;
    return numSelected === numRows;
  }

  /** Selects all rows if they are not all selected; otherwise clear selection. */
  masterToggle() {
    this.isAllSelected() ?
        this.selection.clear() :
        this.dataSource.data.forEach(row => this.selection.select(row));
  }

  /** The label for the checkbox on the passed row */
  checkboxLabel(row?: Material): string {
    if (!row) {
      return `${this.isAllSelected() ? 'select' : 'deselect'} all`;
    }
    return `${this.selection.isSelected(row) ? 'deselect' : 'select'} row ${row.id + 1}`;
  }
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the bottom your table template Html, look if you have this piece of code

```
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
      (click)="selection.toggle(row)">
```

If yes, then remove the `(click)="selection.toggle(row)"` 
this toggles the checkbox even if you click on entire row anywhere.